# WordPress - wp_insert_post() avoid duplication with ACF Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to insert posts from an API (CURL PHP) but I would like to avoid duplication each time I call my ajax function.

I wrote a function that works great but which is based on `get_page_by_path()` (post title). How can I based my function on ACF Field ? For example an ACF Field with an ID.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_exhibitors_from_api', 'post_exhibitors_from_api' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_exhibitors_from_api', 'post_exhibitors_from_api' );

    function post_exhibitors_from_api() {
    
        $exhibitors = $curl_test_list_array;
    
        foreach ($exhibitors as $exhibitor) {
            $exhibitor_title = $exhibitor['name'];
            $exhibitor_slug = sanitize_title($exhibitor_title);
    
            $exhibitor_existing_post = get_page_by_path($exhibitor_slug, 'OBJECT', 'exhibitors');
    
            if ($exhibitor_existing_post === null) {
                $exhibitor_inserted = wp_insert_post([
                    'post_name' => $exhibitor_slug,
                    'post_title' => $exhibitor_title,
                    'post_type' => 'exhibitors',
                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                ]);
    
                if (is_wp_error($exhibitor_inserted)) {
                    continue;
                }
    
                get_exhibitors_acf_fields($exhibitor, $exhibitor_inserted);
    
            } else {
                $exhibitor_existing_id = $exhibitor_existing_post->ID;
                $exhibitor_existing_timestamp = get_field('maj_exposant', $exhibitor_existing_id);
    
                if ($exhibitor['updated_at'] >= $exhibitor_existing_timestamp) {
                    get_exhibitors_acf_fields($exhibitor, $exhibitor_existing_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace these lines

```
    $exhibitor_existing_post = get_page_by_path($exhibitor_slug, 'OBJECT', 'exhibitors');

    if ($exhibitor_existing_post === null) {
```

to this

```
$args = array("post_type" => "product", "meta_key" => "ID", "meta_value" => $yourID );
$posts = get_posts($args);

if (empty($posts)){
```

The whole function will look like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_exhibitors_from_api', 'post_exhibitors_from_api' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_exhibitors_from_api', 'post_exhibitors_from_api' );

    function post_exhibitors_from_api() {
    
        $exhibitors = $curl_test_list_array;
    
        foreach ($exhibitors as $exhibitor) {
            $exhibitor_title = $exhibitor['name'];

            $yourID = $exhibitor['ID'];

            $exhibitor_slug = sanitize_title($exhibitor_title);
            
//change here product to your post type, and $yourID yo value of your key
$args = array("post_type" => "product", "meta_key" => "ID", "meta_value" => $yourID );
$posts = get_posts($args);

if (empty($posts)){ 
                $exhibitor_inserted = wp_insert_post([
                    'post_name' => $exhibitor_slug,
                    'post_title' => $exhibitor_title,
                    'post_type' => 'exhibitors',
                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                ]);
    
                if (is_wp_error($exhibitor_inserted)) {
                    continue;
                }
    
                get_exhibitors_acf_fields($exhibitor, $exhibitor_inserted);
    
            } else {
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
// print_r ($post);

$post_id = $post->ID;
                $exhibitor_existing_id = $post_id
                $exhibitor_existing_timestamp = get_field('maj_exposant', $exhibitor_existing_id);
    
                if ($exhibitor['updated_at'] >= $exhibitor_existing_timestamp) {
                    get_exhibitors_acf_fields($exhibitor, $exhibitor_existing_id);
                }
}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! When you say "and $yourID yo value of your key", it's the ACF field key ?

Comment: Yes, its value of your acf key

Comment: Something like that ? `'meta_key' => 'ID', 'meta_value' => 'field_5a54d0b3810ed'`. I tried that and I got duplicate posts :-(

Comment: We have post, its have meta field with name ID and value 123, you need get value of this meta field (123), then "meta_value" => $yourID

Comment: Do you have in $exhibitor array ID value ? If have

Comment: $yourID = $exhibitor['ID'];

$args = array("post_type" => "product", "meta_key" => "ID", "meta_value" => $yourID );

Comment: and after insert post - update_field( 'ID', $yourID, $exhibitor_inserted);

Comment: Sorry for the long delay ! I was able to test your code and it works fine. But I got a problem with duplicate posts. I have 500 posts to import. Do you know what can I add to prevent those duplicates posts ?

Comment: What field in your import file do you want to use to identify duplicates? Do you have some kind of ID there or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got an ACF field : `id_client`. I would like to compare with this field if a post with `id_client` already exists

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of print_r($exhibitor);